# How to test react component that has relative path nested sub component with Jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

Recently I want to do some unit testing for a react website. I want to import a component, say A. The code looks like:

```
import ComponentA from '../src/containers/ComponentA';
```

And ComponentA is a very complex component with a lot of import inside, like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import request from 'utils/request';
import { ACTIONS } from 'constants/actions';
import { Table, Link } from 'components';  
import ComponentB from './ComponentB';
```

In which utils, constants, and components are local folders and ComponentB is another component used by ComponentA.
So when I tried to import ComponentA, it gives me wired error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

      1 | import React from 'react';
    > 2 | import c3 from 'c3';
      3 | import { isEqual } from 'lodash';
      4 |
      5 | import './C3Chart.scss';
```

The c3 appears in a component in a very base level, it works during the website, how could I fix this? Or should I mock some sub components? Any suggestions?

Comment: There is already an issue on github about that in the c3 git repo: https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/2129

Comment: Thanks, this is a temporary fix for c3 so far, looks solve the problem.